# How to process FormData in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have global $.ajaxPrefilter function that filter values for XSS like this:

```
if (typeof filterXSS == 'function') {
    $.ajaxPrefilter(function(options, origOptions, jqXHR) {
        if (typeof options.data == 'string') {
            var object = {};
            options.data.split('&').forEach(function(pair) {
                pair = pair.split('=');
                object[pair[0]] = decodeURIComponent(pair[1].replace(/\+/g, ' '));
            });
            var newData = {};
            options.data = Object.keys(object).map(function(key) {
                var value = filterXSS(object[key]);
                return key + '=' + encodeURI(value.replace(/ /g, '+'));
            }).join('&');
        } else {
            console.log(typeof options.data);
            console.log(options.data);
        }
    });
}
```

it work fine except when I call ajax request with `FormData` like this:

```
var file = files.shift();
if (file) {
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append(file);
    formData.append('value', '<script>alert("x");</script>');
    $.ajax({
        method: 'POST',
        url: $form.attr('action'),
        data: formData,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false
    });
}
```

how can I process `FormData` inside `$.ajaxPrefilter`, I've try to iterate over `options.data` but only get append:

```
for (var i in options.data) {
    console.log(i);
}
```

Comment: Have not done this but it looks to me like you are creating an empty forms obj.  The examples I see show things like new FormData(this); or formData = new FormData(document.querySelector("form"));

Comment: @Bindrid I copy the code from larger chunk and forget to add `append`.

Comment: Do it **server side** where you can trust the results.